# Awk general-query.log for INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, logging, awk

I have a large mysql general query log which looks like this:

```
110301  2:19:29  268341 Query       SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'sidebars_widgets' LIMIT 1
             268341 Query       SELECT autoload FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'rewrite_rules'
             268341 Query       DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'rewrite_rules'
             268341 Query       SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'rewrite_rules' LIMIT 1
             268341 Query       SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category')  ORDER BY t.name ASC
             268341 Query       SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'page'
             268341 Query       SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 9191 LIMIT 1
             268341 Query       SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND post_parent = 9191
             268341 Query       SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 8805 LIMIT 1
```

I'd like to use AWK to find all the INSERT INTO statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gawk "/INSERT INTO/" query.log
```

I reckon you'll do additional processing, otherwise as noted before, you don't really need awk.

Comment: gawk "/INSERT INTO/ { do stuff with insert statement }" query.log would be what you'll use to do anything other than echoing the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Why awk? grep is better suited.

```
grep -i "INSERT INTO" filename.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use grep with -o option:

```
$ #with your input in /tmp/file
$ grep -O 'SELECT .*' /tmp/file
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'sidebars_widgets' LIMIT 1
SELECT autoload FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'rewrite_rules'
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'rewrite_rules' LIMIT 1
SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category')  ORDER BY t.name ASC
SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'page'
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 9191 LIMIT 1
SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND post_parent = 9191
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 8805 LIMIT 1
```